# Localizing applescript "Menu item title"

Tags: applescript

Anyone knows how can I localize an applescript "Menu item title" from the Info.plist?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Apparently if you look at the Info.plist in the workflow directory in a text editor (as opposed to the 'Property List Editor') you can see that under NSMenuItem you have

```
<key>default</key><string>the title goes here</string>
```

All you need to do is add an entry such as

```
<key>ja</key><string>タイトルはここに行く</string>
```

Hope it helps...